# How can we call stored procedures in Netezza database?

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I am not able to call stored procedures in Netezza database.
Below is my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SUJAY"."ADMIN"."EMPSELECT"()
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
BEGIN
select * from Employee;
END;
END_PROC;
```

When I run this in procedure editor in DB visualizer it throws below error.

> [Code: 1100, SQL State: HY000]  ERROR:  Can't have a SELECT without INTO. Use CALL instead.

[image]

Comment: How are you invoking the procedure?  Have you tried `CALL <procedure>`
See if this helps -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=s-call-another-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error, you will need to modify your SELECT statement to include an INTO clause, which assigns the result of the SELECT statement to a variable. Here is an example of a SELECT statement that includes an INTO clause: something like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO my_variable FROM mytable WHERE somecondition = false;
```

If you want to execute the SELECT statement without capturing the result and without an INTO clause, you could use the CALL statement instead of SELECT, this way it will not raise an exception.

```
CALL EMPSELECT();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But Still I am not able to Fetch all records from table using Stored Procedure. 

Can you specify how we can write Stored Procedure for doing Select Operation ( Select * from table_name ).